# Placing UIImage at tapped image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Currently I have custom UITablViewCell's (BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell) that are displayed in a tableView (myTableView). The custom cell is made up of a UIImageView and a label. When the view loads the labels are populated with the strings from my model. UIImageViews are blank. I want to be able for a user to 'tap' the UIImageView, select a picture from what is stored on their phone and for that image to be saved to the UIImageView.

From the below code I can get the 'tap' gesture, then the pickercontroller pops up and a user selects an image. The way the code is now one image that is selected is set for all of the UIImageViews. Which is understandable. But I want it to be set to that particular UIImageView and don't know how to.

Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDBusinessSelectViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *linkedBusinessParseArray;
//Stores the array of models
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *linkedBusinessParseModelArray;
@property NSUInteger relevantIndex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *tempImageHolder;

@end

#import "BIDBusinessSelectViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BIDBusinessModel.h"
#import "BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell.h"

@interface BIDBusinessSelectViewController () <ImageSelect>
{
    BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *aCell;//define a cell of ur custom cell to hold selected cell
    UIImage *choosenImage; //image to set the selected image
}
@end

@implementation BIDBusinessSelectViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

    self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //create query
    PFQuery *linkedBusinessParseQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"linkedBusinessParseClass"];
    //follow relationship
    [linkedBusinessParseQuery whereKey:@"currentBusinessUserParse" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [linkedBusinessParseQuery whereKey:@"linkRequestSentParse" equalTo:@"Approved"];
    [linkedBusinessParseQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.linkedBusinessParseArray = objects; //store them in my model array
        //loop through model array from Parse
        for (NSDictionary *dict in self.linkedBusinessParseArray) {
            NSString *descPlaceNameParse = [dict objectForKey:@"placeDescriptionParse"];
            NSLog(@"descPlacesNameParse: %@",descPlaceNameParse);
            PFObject *tempObj = (PFObject *) dict;
            NSString *tempObjString = tempObj.objectId;
            NSLog(@"tempObjString (inside dict): %@", tempObjString);

            //storing values from Parse into my model
            BIDBusinessModel *userModel = [[BIDBusinessModel alloc]init];
            userModel.descriptionModelParse = descPlaceNameParse;
            userModel.objectIdModelParse = tempObjString;
            [self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray addObject:userModel];
            NSLog(@"self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray count]);
            //Reload tableview. Has to go here in block otherwise it does not occur
            [self.myTableView reloadData];

        }

    }];


    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }

    choosenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]; //hear u need to set the image for cell assuming that u are setting initially same image for all the cell


}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray.count; //returns count of model NSMutableArray
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Start cellforRowStIndex");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    BIDBusinessModel *bizModel;
    bizModel = self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray[indexPath.row];
    bizModel.image = choosenImage;
    //cell.descLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bid= %d",indexPath.row];//set text from the model//Omitted for my desc
    cell.descLabel.text = bizModel.descriptionModelParse;

    cell.logoImage.image =bizModel.image; //setting the image initially the image when u set in "viewDidLoad" method from second time onwords it will set from the picker delegate method
    //insted of settig the gesture hear set it on the custom cell
    cell.ImageSelectDelegate = self; //setting the delegate
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

// hear implementation of delegate method

- (void)selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:(UIImageView *)logoImgView;
{
    //open up the image picker
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    aCell = (BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *)logoImgView.superview; //her getting the cell

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *aChosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //UIImage holder to transfer to cellForRowAtIndexPath
    choosenImage = aChosenImage;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:aCell];

    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; //hear reloading the selected cell only not entire tableview
    //get the model and set the choosen image
    BIDBusinessModel *bizModel;
    bizModel = self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray[indexPath.row];
    bizModel.image = aChosenImage;


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ImageSelect<NSObject> //for this u need use custom delegate so i did like this
- (void)selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:(UIImageView *)logoImgView;
@end


@interface BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ImageSelect>ImageSelectDelegate; // deleagte

@end

#import "BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell.h"

@implementation BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.logoImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        self.descLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        //set up gesture hear in the custom cell insted in the controller class
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapLogoImage:)];
        [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tap setDelegate:self];
        self.logoImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.logoImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        //[self addSubview:logoImage];
        //[self addSubview:descLabel];

    }
    return self;}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)tapLogoImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)guesture
{
    if([self.ImageSelectDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:)])
    {
        [self.ImageSelectDelegate selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:self.logoImage];//call the delegate method from the selected cell
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Basically I am thinking that I need to somehow 'link' UIImageView to the UITableViewCell. I just don't know how I could go about this linking. Somehow there needs to be a way for it to know that UIImage for the 1st table cell was tapped, or the second table cell etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but the usual way to get which row a tapped UI element is in, is to give it a tag that's equal to the indexPath.row.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, I have changed my question to be more concise. Due to where I am adding the image 'tapLogoImage', I do not think that is possible...?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. You already have images in your table view right? You want to replace the one tapped on with one chosen from the image picker?

Comment: No I do not have images. The tableview is blank (in terms of images). Nothing in the UIImage's. A user can then click on a UIImage view. The pickerViewController pops up and a user can select an image. That image should then populate 'that' particular UIImage. e.g I click on a image of a red ball on the 2nd tableviewcell. The red ball will be displayed in that UIImage and in no others. The rest would be blank. Make sense? Happy to explain further.

Comment: It's hard to advise you on what to do without knowing your data structure. You need some array to hold the image data for your cells. It would be best if it were part of the same structure that provides the label text, but I don't know how that will work with Parse. You can keep a separate array, which won't be too complicated if you don't rearrange the rows or do deletions and insertions.

Comment: redelmar to be honest I do not parse is any issue. I need a way to identify which imageview from a particular cell has been picked. Then I can add to my model and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup for this, i tried but finally i did something like this, go through this u may find some solution. and hope this helps u :)

```
  //in custom cell "BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell.h"
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   //define a delegate method that is called each time when u tapped on cell 
  @protocol ImageSelect<NSObject> //for this u need use custom delegate so i did like this
  - (void)selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:(UIImageView *)logoImgView;
  @end

  @interface BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell : UITableViewCell <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> 
{
   UIImageView *logoImage; //your image holder 
   UILabel *descLabel;     //label
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *logoImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *descLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ImageSelect>ImageSelectDelegate; // deleagte

@end

  //in custom cell "BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell.m"
 #import "BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell.h"

 @implementation BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell 
 @synthesize logoImage;
 @synthesize descLabel;
 @synthesize ImageSelectDelegate;

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {
     // Initialization code
     logoImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
     descLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    //set up gesture hear in the custom cell insted in the controller class
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapLogoImage:)];
     [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
     [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
     [tap setDelegate:self];
     logoImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [logoImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];

     [self addSubview:logoImage];
     [self addSubview:descLabel];

   }
  return self;
}

 - (void)dealloc
{

 [logoImage release];
 [descLabel release];
 [super dealloc];
}


 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 - (void)layoutSubviews
  {
    //in this method simply i am setting the frames of subviews 
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.logoImage.frame = CGRectMake(130, 2, 44,44 );
   self.descLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 2, 60, 44);

 }

 - (void)tapLogoImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)guesture
{
    if([self.ImageSelectDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:)])
   {
      [self.ImageSelectDelegate selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:self.logoImage];//call the delegate method from the selected cell 
   }

}

@end

 //in your view controller class u need to do something like this ;)
 //ViewController.h file
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *aTableView;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath; //no need just try
 @end 

 //in your "ViewController.m" file

  @interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControll erDelegate,ImageSelect>//delegate
{
    BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *aCell;//define a cell of ur custom cell to hold selected cell
    UIImage *choosenImage; //image to set the selected image
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   choosenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.png"]; //hear u need to set the image for cell assuming that u are setting initially same image for all the cell 


}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {  
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }




  - (void)dealloc {
  [aTableView release];

   [super dealloc];
  }


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {


       return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

   return 4; //pass array check array contains valid objects
 }





    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

  BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
     BIDBusinessModel *bizModel;
    bizModel = self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray[indexPath.row];
    bizModel.image = aChosenImage;
   cell.descLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bid= %d",indexPath.row];//set text from the model


   cell.logoImage.image =bizModel.image; //setting the image initially the image when u set in "viewDidLoad" method from second time onwords it will set from the picker delegate method 
    //insted of settig the gesture hear set it on the custom cell 
    cell.ImageSelectDelegate = self; //setting the delegate
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   return cell;

}

 // hear implementation of delegate method

 - (void)selectSetImageForSelectedLogImage:(UIImageView *)logoImgView;
{
   //open up the image picker
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   aCell = (BIDSelectBusinessCustomCell *)logoImgView.superview; //her getting the cell 

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
   UIImage *aChosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   //UIImage holder to transfer to cellForRowAtIndexPath
   choosenImage = aChosenImage;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [aTableView indexPathForCell:aCell];

   [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; //hear reloading the selected cell only not entire tableview
   //get the model and set the choosen image
    BIDBusinessModel *bizModel;
    bizModel = self.linkedBusinessParseModelArray[indexPath.row];
    bizModel.image = aChosenImage;


  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Hi Shan - I attempted your solution and a few variations but had no luck. I have included all of the code available so you (or anyone) don't have to second guess. In the viewDidLoad the parse stuff is just to get the strings that populate the tableview, that is all. It just gets names of places. Then I want a user to be able to select an image. FYI linkedBusinessParseModelArray holds my model objects. Ideally I would probably add the image to a model object and then reload the tableview.

Comment: One thing also to note is that on your solution I do not believe that I could click just the uimageview only. It appeared that the whole tableview cell was clicked each time. This is not what I want. I want a user to be able to click a image, picker pops up, pick one and for that to be stored on the image that they just clicked and no others. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: then u set frame of the imageView to some more bigger and also set  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; it results in no selection of cell.

Comment: I have checked apple docs. I am not to sure how that can help? A user needs to be able to tap and imageview or tap the cell. Let me change my question slightly.

Comment: I did take a look, then at the documentation, I am not to sure how that helps? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: To be clear my current code does work the way I like (mostly). I would like to edit this. I feel that I must be close as I can do everything apart from specifying which UIImageView to update (opposed to all of them). I have tried to bring in a flavour of what you have, please take a look at the new edited questions. Thanks!!

Comment: u need to set a delegate method, so that u can get the exact tapped cell

Comment: if u are free let us chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37651/discussion-between-shan-and-anthony)

Comment: come to chat will help if possible

Comment: Shan - I have now incorporated your answer into my code. I can see the image and the text is displayed but I cannot interact with the tableview cell or the UIImage. Everything I have is now in my recently edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true this would set the image to every row..

Now what you can do is : -

While loading of tableViewCells just assign the tag of UIImageView as the (indexPath.Row).

This would assign unique tags to the ImageView.
You can easily **get the tag of that imageView** while tapping and now you can assign the image to particular imageView through tagValue of that imageView.

This would assign image to a particular imageView as all have unique tags.

Hope you got the answer of your problem.

Comment: I did yes (to an extent). Shan was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Its great, i would love to help if any problem arises.